# How to access li elements that don't show up in the parsed text?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to do a simple html parsing exercise -- get links to images of a user's page in vsco. i got to the part in the code where the page lists the images (div -> ul -> li) but for some reason i'm not getting the 'li' part of the code which is supposed to contain the images. what am i doing wrong? my code to get the ul so far:

```
section = soup.find('body').find('div',class_='page-wrap').find('section').find('div',class_='css-1vgyuuf').find('section').find('ul',style='display:flex;justify-content:center')
```

when i add find('li') nothing shows up. even tried using the li class attribute but nothing shows. thanks in advance

edit: link to vsco page
https://vsco.co/vsco/journal/p/1

Comment: this could be because of javascript rendering, as that information comes after doing extra requests, If you share the site I can help you go further.

Comment: @eLRuLL https://vsco.co/vsco/journal/p/1

Comment: use `findAll` instead of `find` because maybe the first `li` is hidden or has no content. And could you provide the URL for us to try on and see what's wrong??

Comment: @Anwarvic tried that as well, just returns an empty list. I have added the link to the post.

Comment: These `li` are dynamically generated I believe. So, try using `Selenium` with Beautiful Soup.. Selenium mimics the behavior of a browser so it can these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is site is that the information you are looking for is rendered with javascript into the DOM after the page is loaded. Luckily the information is still in the same response, but inside the javascript code.

The necessary information is inside a `script` tag that contains the `__PRELOADED_STATE__` string. Later you need to get the information inside a variable and parse it as json:

```
import re
import json

...

script_text = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=="script" and '__PRELOADED_STATE__' in tag.text)
json_object = re.search('window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ \= (\{.+\})', str(script_text)).group(1)
info = json.loads(json_object)
for key, article in info['entities']['articles'].items():
    for image in article['body']:
        if type(image['content'][0]) is dict:
            print(image['content'][0]['responsiveUrl'])
```

This is just an example on you could get some images, there is more data available inside the `info` variable that you will have to check on your own if you need it.

Comment: wow thanks. this is helped out a ton. i just changed the loop because 'body' wouldn't work for me for some reason, but i was able to see the outputs and work from there. thanks again

Comment: may I ask how you were able to find the preloaded state stuff so quickly? is there a pattern for how stuff like this is hidden into the .js source code?